# Древнерусская литература

Tags: литература, история, грамотная-речь

В чем заключаются особенности древнерусской литературы и культуры?

Answer (score 1):

Вам лекцию прочитать? А самому поискать материал нельзя? Или заглянуть в учебник? [Своеобразие древнерусской литературы (текст лекций)](http://superinf.ru/view_helpstud.php?id=226)